# content frame fragment android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am developing an app in Android Studio using Fragments.

```
    if (id == R.id.nav_agregar_materia) {

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.**content_frame**, new AddNewCourse()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_ver_materias) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.**content_frame**, new ListaCursos()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_agregar_notas) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.**content_frame**, new AgregarNotasPP3()).commit();
```

In the Main Activity class in the method `public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)` I got an error,

> Error:(85, 60) error: cannot find symbol variable content_frame`

Finally, this error occurs sometimes, cause all was working until I add and ImageView in the layout.

Comment: The error says it all

Comment: share your layout file which contains "content_frame".

Comment: "until I add and ImageView in the layout" then that likely means you happened to delete the content frame or at least the ID off of it